# `call WriteString` causing multiply defined symbols error

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I have the following assembly program which on build is giving the error- 
**_IsDigit@0 already defined** 
**one or more multiply defined symbols defined**

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
string_2 BYTE "ABCDE",0

.code


IsDigit PROC
cmp al,'0'
jb ID1 
cmp al,'9'
ja ID1 
test ax,0 
ID1: ret
IsDigit ENDP

main PROC
mov al, '1'
call IsDigit
mov edx,OFFSET string_2
call WriteString

mov bl , 'y'
main ENDP

END main
```

If I remove the line `call WriteString` then the error goes away. Not sure why WriteString is giving
error

Comment: The Irvine library already contains a function called `IsDigit` (with the exact same implementation - did you copy it?). Try renaming your version or use the one from the library if you are not required to write it yourself.

Comment: I got this function from a book. May be the book mentioned it from the irvine library. Yes the error went away when I changed the name.  But that's weird because when I remove the line `call WriteString` the error is no longer there even with the same function name `IsDigit`

Comment: I have few questions somewhat related but not direct - 
1. Is there any link where I could see the functions provided by irvine library?  2. Does visual studio has code complete feature

Comment: 1. yes you can look in the include itself for function names or the library source for more detail. 2. probably not for assembly

Comment: In my program there is include like `INCLUDE Irvine32.inc` Can I enter into this file .inc from microsoft visual studio ?

Comment: It's just a text file, with assembly code. Yes, you can open it in VS. You probably have to browse to it yourself.